# spl_autoload_register() in different directories

Tags: php, class, directory-structure, spl-autoload-register

I have a file that auto loads each of my classes.
This is what it contains:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
});
require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';
require_once 'functions/hash.php';
```

But when I `require_once` this file from another php file that is inside my **ajax** folder, it will try looking for the **classes**, the function will look from my classes with the path: `main_folder/ajax/classes` instead of just `main_folder/classes`.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

**FIX**:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    if (file_exists('classes/' . $class . '.php')) {
       require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
    }
    elseif (file_exists('../classes/' . $class . '.php')) {
       require_once '../classes/' . $class . '.php';
    }
    elseif (file_exists('../../classes/' . $class . '.php')) {
       require_once '../../classes/' . $class . '.php';
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simple use this function just once - in the main file (usually index.php) and not in another files.

However if it's not possible (but I don't see any reason when could it be not possible) you can change it for example that way:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    if (file_exists('classes/' . $class . '.php')) {
       require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
    }
    elseif (file_exists( $class . '.php')) {
       require_once $class . '.php';
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, but the thing is that I keep all my php ajax files in a seperate directory. So even if I call this function in my index.php, it doesn't work as I pull my Ajax through jQuery.
Would the code you have provided still work ?

Comment: If you put this code into AJAX directory, you should simple add / change rules. In above code classes are first checked in `classes` directory and if they don't exist they are then checked in the current directory. So if you have classes in `ajax` directory and you run add this autoloader into some other file in `ajax` directory it should also load file from ajax directory without a problem

Comment: Oh I get it, smart thinking, all I had to do was this:
`elseif (file_exists('../classes/' . $class . '.php')) {
   require_once '../classes/' . $class . '.php';
}

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proper way, It should universally work.

EDIT: Make sure to specify levels on [dirname](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) in order to find the correct path.

```php
spl_autoload_register(function ($classname) {
    $file_realpath = dirname(realpath(__FILE__), levels: 1 /* Change that? */) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . dirname($classname);
    $classpath = sprintf('%s' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '%s.php', $file_realpath, basename($classname, '.{php,PHP}'));

    if (file_exists($classpath)) {
        echo "Loading <b>$classpath</b>...<br>";
        require($classpath);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the absolute path to the classes directory, then just use a full qualified path to get there.

Make sure your document root is correctly configured with your http server. Furthermore this is usually solved by routing all requests to index.php and deriving the base path (document root) from there. Here is your code modified:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    $resolved = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'classes' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $class . '.php';
    if(file_exists($resolved)) {
      require_once $resolved;
    } else {
      // make it known to your that a class failed to load somehow
      return;
    }
})
```

Here is another implementation that I use for simple projects

Comment: Your solution seemed perfect, but it doesn't work... I have checked the my project root and everything looks good.
Got another idea ?

Comment: full path of document root?

Comment: Yes. What is strange is that I get this error, when the path that it is indicating is the correct path: `Failed opening required 'C:/wamp/www/functions/sanitize.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\JamsRecord\coding\core\app_loader.php on line 12`

Comment: You're using windows, so the directory separator needs to be a back slash

Comment: Try it with the new edit. Also, show me your calling code where it fails.

Comment: Still doesn't work.
`Fatal error: Class 'DB' not found in C:\wamp\www\JamsRecord\coding\ajax\login.php on line 18`

Comment: You should edit your question and provide more context. (show the full code)